# Facebook API 2.0 - Is Profile Public for View

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm searching and yet cant find a way,
how to check if page is public for view in facebook

example

```
www.facebook.com/zuck - is public
www.facebook.com/jacek.pietal - is not public
```

I mean, by public, a page can be observable (for public persons)

I need to check this with PHP API

1. I know there was SUPPOSED to be a is_published field on /me GET but there isn't
2. I know accessing /user_id should get this but I can only do this from app-level session and it always can read that because users have accepted my app

Answer (score 0):

Those are not pages, those are user profiles. The `is_published` field is only available for pages, as you can see in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page

Comment: ok so how can I know through the api (What endpoint) to check if user has public profile or not??

Comment: not sure what you mean with "public", i don´t see any difference between those profiles. except for the fact that you can´t add mark as friend, but i don´t think you can read that setting.